# Heroku New Relic Add-on for Java App fails to open newrelic.jar

Tags: java, heroku, newrelic

I [downloaded](http://download.newrelic.com/newrelic/java-agent/newrelic-api/) New Relic 2.12.0 and configured it according to the Heroku [java configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#java-configuration) documentation.

I unzipped the package contents to the root of my spring mvc application directory as indicated in the following image

[image]

Next, I pushed the new files to Heroku:

```
$ git add newrelic
$ git commit -m 'add newrelic'
$ git push heroku master
```

Finally, I bootstrapped the new relic agent:

```
$ heroku config:add JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar'
```

Afterwards, my application failed with the following error and appears to not be able to locate the newrelic.jar file.

The new relic documentation says the JVM args (e.g. -javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar) should include the full path to the newrelic.jar file, but according the the Heroku documentation, -javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar is all that's needed.

```
2013-01-15T19:41:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 47412 target/*.war`
2013-01-15T19:41:11+00:00 app[web.1]: agent library failed to init: instrument
2013-01-15T19:41:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Error occurred during initialization of VM
2013-01-15T19:41:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : newrelic/newrelic.jar
2013-01-15T19:41:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-15T19:41:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**UPDATE**

After checking the newrelic directory on my web dyno, I noticed the jar file was missing. Now I am looking into the cause of the missing jar file.

[image]

**Update**

The .gitignore file in the root of my application directory excludes jar files which prevents the newrelic.jar file from being deployed.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
/target
/.classpath
/.project
/.settings
/tomcat.*
/.idea
/*.iml
=======
*.class

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible you've left something in your `.gitignore` file that ignores jars? If you `heroku run bash` and then `ls newrelic` do you see the jars in there?

Comment: Thanks! I just confirmed that my jar file is missing. I updated my original question to include a screen shot confirming the missing file. I am looking into the possible .gitignore issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with the missing jar file in the target/dependency folder .

For me the problem was the pom file (provided by the Heroku example)

Here is my working POM:

```
                <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
                                <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
                                <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
                                <version>3.12.0</version>
                                <destFileName>newrelic-agent.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
```

And for sure also add New Relic as dependency...

```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
           <artifactId>newrelic-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```